# Is there a way to connect to BZWhll.WhllObj without ActiveX

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, terminal-emulator, hllapi

At the moment I use:

```
//--- BlueZone Connection -----
function bzConnect( session_id ){
   host = new ActiveXObject( "BZWhll.WhllObj" );
   //--- Session ID ---
   bzConnected = host.Connect( session_id );
}
```

To connect my page to run commands from IE to BlueZone. I now have a need to move this processing to chrome however I cannot find a documented way to use "BZWhll.WhllObj" in chrome... any suggestions? I cannot use any extensions to load the page as the code is in an extension that needs to be run from a secure source.

Comment: Chrome doesn't support ActiveX, so no way.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but i generally don't use IE at all. But can an extension be written for IE in the same way one can be written for chrome?

Comment: IE had addons, different beasts. MS Edge supports WebExtensions that are practically the same as Chrome extensions but I doubt it still supports ActiveX.

Comment: [ActiveX has been dropped, Microsoft Edge won't support it.](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/05/06/a-break-from-the-past-part-2-saying-goodbye-to-activex-vbscript-attachevent/)

Comment: Well now this is depressing haha. Thanks guys!